# Can I setup a navigation property between two objects without a unique foreign key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core and have two tables in my database :

- Table 1 (`Contract`)
  Columns : ContractNumber, ContractCode, ProductType
- Table 2 (`ContractRole`)
  Columns: ContractNumber, ContractCode, ProductType, RoleType, RoleName

So, my database doesn't have a foreign key, instead I use two columns (`contractnumber, contractcode`) to reference tables.

My goal is to create my entities, so that I can fetch contracts and then for each Contract I can extract a relevant list of `ContractRoles`. That means using navigation properties.

My code will be something like:

```
[Table("XXXXX")]
public class Contract
{
    public Contract()
    {
        ContractRoles = new HashSet<ContractRole>();
    }

    public ICollection<ContractRole> ContractRoles { get; set; }
}
```

If I had a direct `contractId` foreign key then I could do:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ContractRoles>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Contract)
            .WithMany(x => x.ContractRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ContractId);
```

But I don't! Therefore, I need the reference to be made to two fields: contract number and contract code. Is it possible?

I did make it work by fetching the flat data with a query and then building my proper objects (`Contract` object with a list of `ContractRoles`) later:

```
var result = (from s in _dbContextReadOnly.Contracts
              join sa in _dbContextReadOnly.ContractRoles
              on new { s.ContractNumber, s.ContractCode } equals new { sa.ContractNumber, sa.ContractCode  }                         
              select new FlatContractWithContractRoles
              {
                  ContractNumber = s.ContractNumber,
                  ContractCode  = s.ContractCode,
                  RoleType = sa.RoleType,
                  RoleName = sa.RoleName
              }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Please don't advise me to modify the database at the source, it is not a possibility. I just want to know if I can fetch a `Contract` with a list of `ContractRoles` using the navigation properties directly.

Thanks :) !

Answer (score 0):

I got it! I could just do : 
.HasForeignKey(x => new { x.ContractNumber, x.ContractCode });